Next.js Error: Failed to Determine Locale in NextIntlClientProvider, Please Provide the locale Prop Explicitly
First time asking a question here, sorry if i did not provide some needed info. I am working on a Next.js project and trying to implement internationalization using the next-intl package in a Client Component. However, I am getting the following error:

Error: Failed to determine locale in NextIntlClientProvider, please provide the locale prop explicitly.

Here's my code:
"use client"
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import SearchBar from "@/components/SearchBarComponent/SearchBar";
import styles from "./page.module.scss";
import UserObject from "@/backend/objects/UserObject";
import AuthorCardsList from "@/components/Author/AuthorCardsListComponent/AuthorCardsList";
import { fetchUsers } from "@/backend/request/users";

// for internationalisation
import { NextIntlClientProvider } from 'next-intl';
import { useLocale } from "next-intl";

export default function AuthorsPage(params: { locale: string; query?: string; messages: any; }) {
  const { locale: initialLocale = 'rus', query: initialQuery, messages } = params;
  let currentLocale = useLocale();

  const [users, setUsers] = useState<UserObject[]>([]);
  const [query, setQuery] = useState(initialQuery || "");

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchInitialData = async () => {
      try {
        const initialUsers = await fetchUsers(`?query=${query}`);
        setUsers(initialUsers);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error fetching users:", error);
      }
    };

    fetchInitialData();
  }, [query]);

  return ( 
    <div>
      <NextIntlClientProvider locale={initialLocale} messages={messages}>
        <SearchBar onSearch={(newQuery) => setQuery(newQuery)} />
      </NextIntlClientProvider>
      
      <div className={styles.results_wrapper}>
        {users.length ? (
          <AuthorCardsList users={users} />
        ) : (
          <p className="results_not_found_message">Автор не найден.</p>
        )}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}


and this is my middleware
import createMiddleware from 'next-intl/middleware';
import {routing} from './i18n/routing';

export default createMiddleware(routing);

export const config = {
  matcher: [
    // Enable a redirect to a matching locale at the root
    '/',

    // Set a cookie to remember the previous locale for
    // all requests that have a locale prefix
    '/(rus|kaz)/:path*',

    // Enable redirects that add missing locales
    // (e.g. `/pathnames` -> `/en/pathnames`)
    '/((?!_next|_vercel|.*\\..*).*)'
  ]
};

What I've tried:
I am passing locale and messages explicitly to the NextIntlClientProvider, but the error still persists.
I’ve also tried setting a default locale as ‘rus’, and while the error no longer appears, the text is not translated. Instead, I get the key names (e.g., Authors.title) as placeholders, indicating that the corresponding translation message for the locale is not being loaded.
The goal:
I want to ensure the NextIntlClientProvider correctly receives the locale and messages props without throwing this error.
Additional context:

Next.js version: 14
next-intl version: latest
The app uses the app router (/app directory structure).


how you fixed it?
